# Pandas replace by condition in the 1st row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, replace, series

I have a table:

| Object | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| reference | 10 | 0 | 7 | 0 |
| Obj1 | 14 | 9 | 1 | 30 |
| Obj2 | 1 | 16 | 0 | 0 |
| Obj3 | 9 | 21 | 3 | 17 |
| Obj4 | 11 | 0 | 4 | 22 |

And I want to transform it by condition: if 1st row of any column is =0, then other rows of this column can be either 0 or 1. If the current value is >0, than it becomes 1, if it's 0, than it remains 0.

Resulting table is:

| Object | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| reference | 10 | 0 | 7 | 0 |
| Obj1 | 14 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Obj2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Obj3 | 9 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| Obj4 | 11 | 0 | 4 | 1 |

I've tried this variant:

```
for column in df:
    df[column] = np.where((df[column][0] == 0) & (df[column] != 0), 1, 0)
```

but it resets to zero all columns, where 1st row isn't equal to 0.
How can I do this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select first row by `df.iloc[0]` and then check which columns in this row are equal `0`. Then change the particular columns:

```py
first_row = df.iloc[0]
zero_columns = first_row[first_row == 0].index

df.loc[:, zero_columns] = (df.loc[:, zero_columns] > 0).astype(int)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      Object  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
0  reference    10     0     7     0
1       Obj1    14     1     1     1
2       Obj2     1     1     0     0
3       Obj3     9     1     3     1
4       Obj4    11     0     4     1
```